# Generate response based on request

Tags: pact

In PACT DSL, is it possible to access the request when generating the response?

What I want to do, is to copy some part of the request to the response. This would be very handy when launching the [pact-stub-server](https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-stub-server) to imitate the provider.

A simple case could be this: if a request is made to `/users/<SOME-UUID>`, then let the mock return the body of `{ "id": <SOME-UUID> }` (with the same `SOME-UUID`). I don't want to mock one, particular UUID, but the generic path. This way, when starting the [pact-stub-server](https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-stub-server), a reasonable response could be returned, so that the ID in the response matches the ID in the request, no matter what UUID is requested in the URL.

Spring Cloud Contract equivalent for this is `fromRequest()` [set of methods](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-contract/reference/html/project-features.html#contract-dsl-referencing-request-from-response), e.g. `fromRequest().url()`